# URL роутинг по алиасам

Tags: php_pdo, php, маршрутизация, router

1) Лучше реализовать, чтото типа:

```
 <?php
    $route = new Routing();
    $route->foo('/example', 
                           array(
                               'MainController' => 'example'
                         )
                      );
    ?>
```

Первый аргумент алиас, полученный из url, второй массив, где указано куда обращаться если ссылка совпала с алиасом.

2) Или хранить в БД, поля "ссылка" и "алиас", и при каждом запросе страницы, делать выборку и показывать ту ссылку, которая совпала.

3) Вот еще вариант, на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/134406/). Там через xml. Можно хоть и ini файлы использовать?

Тут я не рассматривал вариант, где URL разбивается на части, а потом в зависимости от ссылки напрямую вызывается controller, method, action ...

Так вот, товарищи, спрашиваю вас, как более опытных, какой подход лучше? Если приведенные мной варианты неудачны, прошу предоставить более удобную и безопасную альтернативу :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно хранить правила в базе, это создаст на нее большую нагрузку.
Советую посмотреть как сделано в [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html),
там это очень хорошо реализовано.
А сам формат данных в котором будет все хранить - это уже другое дело. Кто-то в php-массивах это делает, кто-то в json-файле.
Вообще в статье с хабра все хорошо описано.

Comment: Спасибо. Полез на гитхаб...

Comment: русскоязычный перевод - https://symfony.com.ua/doc/current/routing.html